# SQL - return max date with many to many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: p, p2l, l

```
p - p_id; 
p2l - p_id, l_id
l - l_id, date
```

How do I get max(date) for each p_id?

Is any of this query correct?

1

```
SELECT plot_id, max(l.date) as l_maxDate
FROM p2l
LEFT JOIN l ON p2l.l_id = l.l_id
Group by p_id
```

2

```
SELECT plot_id, maxDate.maxLDate,
FROM p2l
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT l_id, MAX(date) AS maxLDate
  FROM l
  GROUP BY l_id) maxDate 
ON maxDate.l_id = p2l.l_id 
GROUP BY p_id
```

Comment: what you mean by max date is it the latest date?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.p_ID, MAX(l.date) max_date
FROM    p
        INNER JOIN p2l
            ON p.p_id = p2l.p_ID
        INNER JOIN l 
            ON p2l.l_id = l.l_id
GROUP   BY p.p_ID
```

but if you don't want the records from table `p`. you can just remove that table from the join.

```
SELECT  p2l.p_ID, MAX(l.date) max_date
FROM    p2l
        INNER JOIN l 
            ON p2l.l_id = l.l_id
GROUP   BY p2l.p_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First one seems correct, would give you the max date and nulls for no matches, though you will not get results for p_id in table p and not in table p2l
2. This one is very interesting, It assumes l_id is not unique in the l table. and it removes p_id where thre is no join. But this extra statement to select max is overhead and does not add much.

To get all p_id (including ones with no link you shoud do)

```
SELECT  p.p_ID, MAX(l.date) max_date
FROM    p
        LEFT JOIN p2l
            ON p.p_id = p2l.p_ID
        LEFT JOIN l 
            ON p2l.l_id = l.l_id
GROUP   BY p.p_ID
```